# Is my JOIN + GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT query correct?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, group-by

I'm new to SQL and I want to implement the following query:

I've got two tables, `LicenseTbl` and `UnlockTbl`:

`LicenseTbl` contains information about a purchased software license:

> LicenseID, ProgramID, Owner, Location, OrderNo, BlockTime

`UnlockTbl` contains information about a specific software registration:

> UnlockID, LicenseID (foreign key into LicenseTbl), Timestamp, SerialNo, Key, UninstallTime

where BlockTime and UninstallTime contain a timestamp if the license was blocked or the software uninstalled and `NULL` otherwise.

I want to devise a query that gives me ALL LicenseIDs for which the following conditions hold:

> - belongs to a given customer,
> - is not blocked,
> - is either not listed in the UnlockTbl or there are < X different SerialNo's in lines which are not marked as uninstalled.

I have written this, but I'm not sure if it is absolutely correct (it's one of my first SQL queries ever):

```
SELECT LicenseID FROM LicenseTbl
JOIN UnlockTbl
   ON (LicenseTbl.LicenseID = UnlockTbl.LicenseID) 
WHERE  LicenseTbl.OrderNo   = '$givenOrderNo'
   AND LicenseTbl.Owner     = '$givenOwner'
   AND LicenseTbl.Location  = '$givenLocation'
   AND LicenseTbl.BlockTime IS NULL
   AND UnlockTbl.UninstallTime IS NULL
GROUP BY LicenseTbl.LicenseID, UnlockTbl.Key
HAVING COUNT(*) < $X
```

(which is supposed to mean, list all licenses which have only been used less than X times simultaneously. I would prefer those that have been used the least first but don't know how to sort like that.)

Comment: Well, what happens when you run it? The test of whether it is correct would be whether you get the data back that you want. You can't break any of the data on the server with a `SELECT` so just try it...

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing, and it seems to work on my test data, but I don't know how to sort by count. The real database has thousands of entries, so I can't be sure if nothing is missing.

Comment: Well what I would do is create 8 records in your test data: 1 that should be returned, 3 that break one each of the exclusion conditions, 3 that break 2 of the exclusion conditions in every combination, and 1 that breaks all 3. Run your query, and make sure you only get the one record back. If that works, it can be safely assumed that it will scale up.

Comment: I agree with Dave.  There are two types of test you generally need with SQL queries; logical and performance.  Performance tests need large *(realistic)* sets of data.  But logical tests only *need* data that describe *all* the corner cases that exist.  It can be small in size, fabricated, and so easy to validate.  *However*, you may have forgotten a corner case that you need to test; identifying all cases requires a very rigorous approach.  In which case it's also lwys good to take random cases from real data and validate them by hand *or* some other automated logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good start, but I would change the query to the following...

```
SELECT
  LicenseID
FROM
  LicenseTbl
LEFT JOIN
  UnlockTbl
    ON  UnlockTbl.LicenseID = LicenseTbl.LicenseID
    AND UnlockTbl.UninstallTime IS NULL
WHERE
      LicenseTbl.OrderNo   = '$givenOrderNo'
  AND LicenseTbl.Owner     = '$givenOwner'
  AND LicenseTbl.Location  = '$givenLocation'
  AND LicenseTbl.BlockTime IS NULL
GROUP BY
  LicenseTbl.LicenseID
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT UnlockTbl.SerialNo) < $X
ORDER BY
  COUNT(DISTINCT UnlockTbl.SerialNo)
```

**1). `LEFT JOIN`**

A `LEFT JOIN` ensures that all rows in `LicenseTbl` are returned, even if there are no matches in the `UnlockTbl` table.  *(If there are no matches, the `UnlockTbl` table's values are all represented as `NULL`.)*

**2). `UnlockTbl.UninstallTime IS NULL` in the `JOIN` and not the `WHERE`**

The `WHERE` clause is applied *after* the `JOIN`.  This means that any records in `UnlockTbl` where `UninstallTime` have a real value *(NOT NULL)* get joined and *then* get filtered out.  This in turn means that if *all* the relevant records in `UnlockTbl` have a non-NULL value in `UninstallTime`, all the rows for that License will get filtered.

**3). `GROUP BY` on just the license, not the Key.**

Simply, I don't know why you had it there, and it doesn't appear in the English description of what you want.

As you want a list of LicenseIDs, grouping by *only* that field ensures that you get one record per LicenseID.

**4). `HAVING` clause modified to look at `COUNT(DISTINCT SerialNo)`**

`COUNT(*)` counts all records.  Even if there was no match *(All the `UnlockTbl` values appearing as NULL)*, this would return `1`.

`COUNT(SerialNo)` counts only records where `SerialNo` is NOT NULL.  If there was no match *(All the `UnlockTbl` values appearing as NULL)*, this would return `0`.

`COUNT(DISTINCT SerialNo)` also counts only records where `SerialNo` is NOT NULL, but treats duplicates of the sme value as just 1 entry.

**5). `ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT SerialNo)`**

Takes the same value as is being filtered in the `HAVING` clause, and orders by it.

Comment: well documented to clarify the different elements and how they tie together.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that is *really* helpful! (for (3), I probably have had the wrong impression that a `GROUP BY` on the serial number would somehow influence my count. And `Key` was a typo/"thinko" for `SerialNo`.)